# Pagenumbering - center, foot

Tags: page-numbering

how can I change the pagenumbering: I want to have numbers in the center in the bottom part of the page and I want to have at the first page number 5.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I did it this way and it works: \setcounter{page}{5}. So, sorry for my impatience.

Answer (score 1):

You just use `\setcounter{page}{5}`, the default option is to have the numbering centered.

For more useful hints on this:
for the page numbering , you just use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` when you don't want to have page number and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` when you want it, and for setting the starting number, you use: `\setcounter{page}{5}` --> here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
hello 1
\newpage
hello 2
\newpage
hello 3
\newpage
hello 4
\newpage
hello 5
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\end{document}
```

Like this - it will be centered according to your needs

Regards